Why Isn't SQLAlchemy's order_by Sorting URLs?
I'm working on a Flask application using SQLAlchemy where I need to consistently sort URLs stored in a database. The goal is to have a consistent ordering of competitor URLs so that when comparing products with the same competitors, the order of the URLs is identical, regardless of whether they start with http:// or https://.

I'm using SQLite as the testing database.
The Competitor model has a url column defined as db.String(256), and I'm trying to order by this column.
My current approach is:

competitors = Competitor.query.filter_by(product_id=product.id).order_by(func.lower(Competitor.url).asc()).all()

Despite using order_by(func.lower(Competitor.url).asc()), the sorting doesn't seem to be effective. URLs are not sorting correctly, regardless of whether I use asc() or desc().
Is there a way to consistently sort URLs directly within the SQLAlchemy query using order_by? If not, would a Python approach be the best alternative, or is there a more efficient method to achieve consistent URL sorting?
I attempted fetching all competitors and sorting the URLs after stripping the http:// and https:// schemes:
order_by(
    func.lower(func.replace(Competitor.url, 'http://', '')).asc(),
    func.lower(func.replace(Competitor.url, 'https://', '')).asc()
)


Unfortunately, this did not work as expected.
Update: After conducting a series of tests, the issue with the sorting anomaly was caused by assigning query results directly to the relationship attribute competitors. When the query results is assigned to a separate variable (e.g., product_competitors), the sorting behaved as expected.

Can you extract the generated SQL statement and run it manually against your database, to isolate whether the problem is in SQLite or SQLAlchemy?

Thank you. I ran the generated SQL query manually against SQLite database:
SELECT competitor.url FROM competitor WHERE competitor.product_id = 1 ORDER BY lower(competitor.url) ASC;
Results are sorted as expected. It seems the issue might lie elsewhere or in SQLAlchemy.

Update: After conducting a series of tests, the issue with the sorting anomaly was caused by assigning query results directly to the relationship attribute competitors. When the query results is assigned to a separate variable (e.g., product_competitors), the sorting behaved as expected.
